# Preposition usage in “at/in the corner of the room”

Tags: prepositions

> He is sitting **at/in** the corner of the room.

Which preposition is more appropriate in this example?

Comment: **In** the corner of the room (an enclosure), but **at** the corner of the table (a solid object).

Answer (score -1):

Which is correct?

Lying in the corner was the huge lion.

Lying at the corner was the huge lion.

Q. **Is there any different in meaning?**

---

**Lying in the corner (of the room/cage etc) was a huge lion.**

**Lying at the corner of the street was a huge lion**. ( particular place , street corner as opposed to a "general comment" lying in the street")

---

**in** preposition (INSIDE) inside a container, place, or area, or surrounded or closed off by something:

**at** preposition (PLACE) used to show an exact position or particular place:

All Ref CED **In**       [**At**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at)